# Dart Language Extension Method

Tags: flutter, dart, extension-methods

I am reading extension method in dart official documentation, and reached the bottom of the [document](https://dart.dev/guides/language/extension-methods). Here, the documentation mentioned the line `List<T> operator -() => reversed.toList();` as a extension method on `List<T>`.
Here is the complete code.

```
extension MyFancyList<T> on List<T> {
  int get doubleLength => length * 2;
  List<T> operator -() => reversed.toList();
  List<List<T>> split(int at) => [sublist(0, at), sublist(at)];
}
```

What does mean `operator -()`, `operator +(List<T> t)`,and `operator *(List<T> t)` and how can I use these as extension method on List?

Comment: `final list = [1,2,3]; print(-list);`

Answer (score 0):

It means you can actually use it as an operator on the list. For example:

```
final list = [1,2,3,4,5];
print(-list);
```

prints [5,4,3,2,1]

Personally, I would not implement a revers like this. I think it would be quite unclear for other developers, while the `reversed` method is very clear on what it does. However, I understand it is just an example on how to define an operator in an extension.

`operator +(List<T> t)` and `operator *(List<T> t)` is between two lists. For example:

```
final a = [1,2];
final b = [3,4];
print(a + b);
```

prints [1,2,3,4]

Comment: Thanks @TmKVU It so simple :-D. I am too silly ;-)

Comment: What about `+(List<T> t)` and `*(List<T> t)`?

Comment: I added them to my answer